# Google OAuth : How to accept consent without browser

Tags: java, oauth, gmail

I have a JAVA web service on AWS which need to send email through my service gmail account. I have setup almost everything and got the URL which asks me to open in the browser and accept the consent. However, I can't open the URL in AWS with the browser. I tried to open the URL on my local computer but it doesn't work since the URL need to redirect to server localhost after accepting the request.

Is there any way to accept the request without a browser? Can I just give my service account and password in the console then accept the request?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please explain a bit more about what all components you have in your application. You're talking about URL for accepting consent, guess you are talking about the google sign in URL. That is applicable if you have a UI application of your own, to which you wish to redirect after authentication. Is that so? Where is the email composed, do you have a UI too? If all you need to do is send email through the service account, that can be done on the web service side with javamail and SMTP. Why do you need to use oauth? Instead, if you intent to send email using the account of whoever user is using your application, then oauth makes sense.

Comment: The service is simple. Users leave their email address and ask for a service email. Server will compose the mail and send email to users through my own gmail service account. What I am trying to do is to authorize server to access the gmail service account so I could use gmail api to send email to users.

Comment: I basically follow the introduction https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java and stock in step 4 since I can't open the URL in browser in AWS server remotely.

Comment: Just use java mail and SMTP with Gmail to send emails to those users. You've a service gmail account that you wish to send emails from and you wish to send it to end users. This is not really a valid use case for oauth. Here's a good tutorial about how to use javamail with Gmail. [link](https://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)

Comment: I see. Thanks very much.

Comment: Did some digging, I guess what you are doing can also be done with a little tweak of the sample code. You'll need to get the pem or pk12 file from Google API console and instead of Credentials, use GoogleCredentials as `Credential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId("yourserviceaccount@gmail.com")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromPemFile(pemFile)
                .build();` I have not tried it yet, though.

Comment: Late reply. I finally solve this question by running my JAVA service locally and generate the credential by using browser. Then put files to server through FTP... Gonna spend some time to implement the correct practice